# foreach iteration to match array contents

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array takes values matching a specified key and echo's out the results in a table. I want to then have functionality that when you click on each of these items it pops up a modal with further item details.

I've got the JSON back from the source that contains the key/value pairs. I've filled an array with values that match a given key and I've got these printing out. I have the code to open the modal. Now I need the modal to pull the required details, so I've repeated the above steps to fill an array with the values from the [DESCRIPTION] key.

```
  $subjectList = array();
  foreach($responseResult as $subject) {       // Loop over JSON and fill an  
    $subjectList[] = $subject['subject'];      // array with subject.
  }
  $modalContent = array();
  foreach($responseResult as $arrayItem) {     // Loop over JSON and fill an
    $modalContent[] = $arrayItem['summary'];   // array with details.
  }
  $submit = array_slice($subjectList, 0, 50);
  foreach($submit as $use) {
    echo "<tr><th scope='row'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span></th><td><a href='#' style='color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>{$use}</a>";
  }


    <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
      <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Juno | Ticket Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
         <?php
           echo $modalItem;
         ?>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
          <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-wman' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I need to do some sort of matching between the array indices so when the user clicks a given [SUBJECT] they get the corresponding [DESCRIPTION] for that subject. I have a vague idea of using array_keys() maybe, or if statements?

The code I have opens the modal and drops that same [DESCRIPTION] into every [SUBJECT]. I feel like I'm so close!

Comment: You should provide an example of `$responseResult`  to avoid we are running into a trap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want something like this:

```
$responseResult =
[
  [
    'subject' => 'one',
    'summary' => 'summary one',
  ],
  [
    'subject' => 'two',
    'summary' => 'summary two',
  ],
  [
    'subject' => 'three',
    'summary' => 'summary three',
  ],
];

error_clear_last();

$keyValuePairs = @array_combine
( array_slice(array_column($responseResult, 'subject'), 0, 50),
  array_slice(array_column($responseResult, 'summary'), 0, 50)
);

if(error_get_last())
  echo 'Error handling';
else
{
  echo "summary of subject two: {$keyValuePairs['two']} <br>\n";

  foreach ($keyValuePairs as $k => $v)
    echo "$k => $v <br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's what you're looking for?

```
$subjectList = [];
$modalContent = [];

foreach($responseResult as $index => $item) {  // Loop over JSON and fill an  
    $subjectList[$index] = $item['subject'];   // array with subject.
    $modalContent[$index] = $item['summary'];  // array with details.
}
```

Comment: Not quite, but it does tidy up my bloated effort! Thanks!